# No muestra resultado mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alguien tiene idea de porqué al hacer la consulta que sea con mysqli (aunque no exista la tabla en cuestión en la BBDD) da siempre resultados en blanco? Estoy atascado con una consulta a la BBDD, en el backoffice funciona correctamente y la misma consulta en público no muestra nada.

Saludos

---Nuevo a partir de aquí---

Texto en el index.php de la web

```
    include $nivel.'panel/includes/php/conexion.php'; 

    $sqlmarca = "SELECT * FROM marcas";
    echo $sqlmarca;
    $res_marca = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlmarca) or die('Consulta fallida: '.mysqli_error($conexion));  

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res_marca));
    {
    echo '<br>Hola<br>';
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el $nivel solo añade /../ o no a una ruta, dependiendo del nivel en el que te encuentres, es decir, si estás en raiz sería / si estás en una carpeta inferior sería /../ , etc
En teoría el 'Hola' de arriba debería salir más de una vez, puesto que en la BBDD tengo varias marcas.

Texto en el backoffice (este funciona)

```
    //Listado de Marcas
    $sql_marcas = "SELECT * FROM marcas ORDER BY marca";
    $res_marcas = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_marcas) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_marcas)) 
    { 
    Echo 'Marcas';
    }
    // Liberar resultados
    mysqli_free_result($res_marcas);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
PD: pregunta editada

Comment: Hola Franxo. Bienvenido. ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código que estás usando? Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta para agregarlo (y haciendo click en el botón `{ }` para darle formato aal código y que se pueda leer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, te sobra un `;` al final del `while`:

```
 while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res_marca)); <---
```

Comment: Gracias! Era eso.